# Does a .txt file get indexed? How to prevent this?

Tags: .htaccess, robots.txt

I've got a .txt file that I'm using to store chat info. what I'm trying to figure out is how to prevent this page from getting indexed as I'm creating a more friendly version using tthat info. So I have chat.txt where it is recorded then I have pretty-chat-history.php in which I echo that page within my actual page. Is there a way to prevent chat.txt from being picked up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to the htaccess file:

```
 <FilesMatch "(chat.txt)$">
  Order allow,deny
  deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Am I still able to use that file @Alejo JM ?

Comment: from PHP ? yes, from the browser not, http://somedomain.com/chat.txt Forbidden, right ?

Comment: Thanks @Alejo JM I'll need to test this I guess...not an immediate end outcome, but this is what I need. We'll see the effects down the road..Thanks!